# Spark Window Function to build timeline

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I am trying to build a timeline and I want to be able to detect timeline discontinuations. I have this test df:

| ID | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2012-12-01 |
| 1 | 2012-12-02 |
| 1 | 2012-12-03 |
| 1 | 2012-12-05 |
| 1 | 2012-12-06 |
| 1 | 2012-12-07 |
| 1 | 2012-12-10 |
| 1 | 2012-12-11 |

And I would like to get a timeline with start-end dates likes this:

| ID | date | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2012-12-01 | 2012-12-03 |
| 1 | 2012-12-05 | 2012-12-07 |
| 1 | 2012-12-10 | 2012-12-11 |

I've been trying with:

```
columns = ['id','snapshot_date']
data = [
('1','2012-12-01'),
('1','2012-12-02'), 
('1','2012-12-03'),
('1','2012-12-05'),
('1','2012-12-06'),
('1','2012-12-07'),
('1','2012-12-10'),
('1','2012-12-11')]

dftest = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)

w1 = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy(F.col('date'))

df2 = (df1.withColumn("group_date", F.when( ~(F.date_add(F.col('snapshot_date'), -1) == F.lag(F.col("snapshot_date"), 1, 0).over(w1)), F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))).filter(F.col('group_date')>1)
```

But not sure how to get the correct end date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of sessionization, you can learn more about sessionization with spark with [this article](http://www.janvsmachine.net/2017/09/sessionization-with-spark.html).

And if we adapt the solution with window in the article cited above to your specific case, we get the following code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

columns = ['id','snapshot_date']
data = [
('1','2012-12-01'),
('1','2012-12-02'), 
('1','2012-12-03'),
('1','2012-12-05'),
('1','2012-12-06'),
('1','2012-12-07'),
('1','2012-12-10'),
('1','2012-12-11')]

dftest = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)

w1 = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('snapshot_date')

df2 = dftest \
  .withColumn('session_change', F.when(F.datediff(F.col('snapshot_date'), F.lag('snapshot_date').over(w1)) > 1, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))) \
  .withColumn('session_id', F.sum('session_change').over(w1)) \
  .groupBy('ID', 'session_id') \
  .agg(F.min('snapshot_date').alias('date'), F.max('snapshot_date').alias('end')) \
  .drop('session_id')
```

That will give us the following `df2`:

```
+---+----------+----------+
|ID |date      |end       |
+---+----------+----------+
|1  |2012-12-01|2012-12-03|
|1  |2012-12-05|2012-12-07|
|1  |2012-12-10|2012-12-11|
+---+----------+----------+
```